# How to fix the error: Attempted import error: 'Navlink' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

./src/components/HeaderComponent.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand, Nav, NavbarToggler, Collapse, NavItem, Jumbotron } from 'reactstrap';
import { Navlink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.5.1"
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: Just remove `import { Navlink } from 'react-router-dom` or import `Navlink` from correct dependency. Also please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions on StackOverflow and lean more about [formatting style](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Then how do I import Navlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: I have already added that. Still getting this error

Comment: That downvote wasn't by me. Anyway, this is also throwing errors.

Comment: Line 33:28:  'Navlink' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Comment: You have to use NavLink in import and in jsx too.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I mean, inside your component you used Navlink at certain point. But it was just a typo, so try write "NavLink", because that's what you imported.

Comment: <NavLink to="/whatever"></NavLink> instead of <Navlink to="/whatever"></Navlink>

Answer (score 2):

simply try:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

instead of

```
import { Navlink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

i.e its 'NavLink' not 'Navlink'