# 'Navlink' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs

I am using ReactJs and I am following a video that has a different version of ReactJs. I am using React 17.0.2 and I have the following error.

Attempted import error: 'Navlink' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
Any idea?

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using?

Comment: Provide import strings

Comment: Your component name is incorrect, it should be `import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the error: Attempted import error: 'Navlink' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234454/how-to-fix-the-error-attempted-import-error-navlink-is-not-exported-from-re)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component you are trying to import is named NavLink (camelcase) and not Navlink as you specified.

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

Comment: faleminderit shqipe @Astrit